# problemas com acentos ao executar o php

Tags: php, ubuntu, acentuação, lamp

Bom dia galera, estou com problemas ao executar o código `php` no `browser`, em qualquer browser, ele não reconhece o acento. 
Foi preciso usar a seguinte linha de código para que o acento fosse reconhecido: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')`;
Porém eu queria uma solução um pouco mais definitiva, em que não fosse preciso estar sempre fazendo o uso desta linha. 
E detalhe estou usando uma distribuição `Linux Ubuntu` com `LAMP server`.

Comment: Como está o `meta charset` do HTML ?

Comment: Seu arquivo esta salvo SEM BOM? você esta pegando estes dados de um banco de dados? você deficou o `charset` no html?

Comment: Olá amigos, não estou pegando estes dados do banco de dados, naverdade comecei a desenvolver código em php no ubuntu hoje e já me deparei com esse problema e estou a procura de uma solução.

Comment: Você viu a dica que eu dei e a que o Rafael deu ?

Comment: Anelisa para deixar permanente, tem que configurar o header direto no Apache. Vide documentação do Apache e resposta do @André. Certifique-se de não usar <meta> para isto na página enquanto não arrumar o header, para não dar confusão.

Answer (score 2):

inclua ou altere a linha no arquivo /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset

**AddDefaultCharset UTF-8** ou **AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1** ( para o padrão pt-br).

Reinicie o Apache